# Update a datatable with reference key from another datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have one datatable, say 'dtEmp', with columns     `[EmployeeID][CompanyID][CompanyName]`
and another say 'dtCompany' with columns `[CompanyID][CompanyName]`

I want to update 'dtEmp' with respective Company names in column `[CompanyName]`

Plese guide. I tried searching this but I could not find exact words to search :(

Comment: Use join on `CompanyId` on two tables.

Comment: Thanks. Join returns me combind result. I am not getting how to **update** the datatablle `'dtEmp'`. Do I need to iterate again or there is better way

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for(int i = 0; i < dtCompany.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < dtEmp.Rows.Count ; j++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(dtCompany.Rows[i]["CompanyID"]) == 
            Convert.ToString(dtEmp.Rows[j]["CompanyID"]))
        {
            dtEmp.Rows[j]["CompanyName"] =
            Convert.ToString(dtCompany.Rows[i]["CompanyName"]);
        }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes @Nikhil. I got this. I thought there may be better way with linq/inner join. Or maybe am I overthinking :P

Comment: @parixit: Wait let me see.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from t1 in dtEmp
join t2 in dtCompany on t1.CompanyID equals t2.CompanyID
select new { t1.EmployeeID, t1.CompanyID, t2.CompanyName}).ToList()
```

I don't know what your long term purpose is for updating the datatable, however using something like this would provide you a list of an anonymous object which would contain the 3 fields that you needed. You could potentially hard cast these to strongly typed Datarows and then create a brand new table (or update your existing one) with each row.

Answer (score 0):

Linq itself cannot do update.
Assuming Typed DataTable, simply:

```
foreach(var rowEmp in dtEmp)
{
    var rowComp = dtCompany
                  .Where(r => r.CompanyID == rowEmp.CompanyID)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
    if(rowComp == null)
        rowEmp.SetCompanyNameNull();
    else
        rowEmp.CompanyName = rowComp.CompanyName;
}
```

(Ignoring the case of the content having null or DBNull, do null-check if required please.)

Similar logic is applicable to general DataTable.